# Error transaction underpriced when trying to deploy a contract

Tags: contract-deployment

first I wanna say that I'm starting to learn solidity using a course.
I got to the point where I deploy my first contract using infura and truffle, but I get this error "Error: transaction underpriced".

```
const Web3= require('web3');
const {interface, bytecode}= require('./compile');
const provider= new HDWalletProvider(
  seed
  infura API
(just didn't copy these)
);
const web3=new Web3(provider);

const deploy= async ()=>{
   const accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();

   console.log('Deploying from', accounts[0])

  const result= await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
   .deploy({data: '0x' + bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!']})
   .send({from: accounts[0]})

   console.log('Address:', result.options.adress);
};
deploy();
```

That's all I have.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is likely the account have a pending transaction. To replace a pending transaction you have to use the same nonce an increase gasPrice by 10%.

Comment: I'm using my personal account, and I don't have any pending transactions.